# Visual Studio 2015 Ajax Request fails using Device in Apache Cordova Android platform 6

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova, content-security-policy, apache-cordova

Team Apache,

This question I am posting, while trying all available resources about ajax request failed in TACO in Vs 2015. I am using API with localhost, used IP address of localhost , tried with server hosted API, but I always get status = 0. when I use DEvice for Android. With Ripple Nexus it work fine.I am struggling for a week and no luck yet.

I am using VS 2015 , Android platform 6.

I have added whitelist plugin as well, and tried to add all type of access origin:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

OR

```
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
```

Added meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lollipop introduced a number of changes to the Android security model. To support the new model, Cordova 5+ introduced the whitelist plugin and a new security model that deprecated `<access origin="*">`. Your app has all the right pieces, but you haven't configured them correctly.

1. **Whitelist plugin**
2. **Content Security Policy (meta tag)** declares what resources can be accessed in the client-side code
3. `<allow-intent>` tells the native/compiled app what sources can be used for data (e.g. XHR)
4. `<allow-navigation>` tells the native/compiled app what sources can be used for content (e.g. full page navigation)

Note that the CSP and `<allow-intent/navigation>` tags must match. The CSP is used by your client-side code in the webview. The `<allow-intent/navigation>` tags are used by the native/compiled app wrapper.

To enable data access to domains outside of the app itself, you need to modify your content-security-policy (CSP) to identify the outside authority. There's an excellent tutorial [available here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=617697), but I've provided an example below. This CSP allows XHR requests and content to be loaded from https://thecatapi.com (a silly API that returns cat images):

### In index.html...

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' content-src: https://thecatapi.com data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com https://thecatapi.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

### In config.xml...

```
<allow-intent href="https://thecatapi.com/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://thecatapi.com/* />
```

Comment: Hi Ryan,  Thanks for the solution. I will cross check again in my app as you have suggested. I would like to know one more thing, does new security policy allow only https url, can't I use http and can I use localhost also? since my app still in development phase as well as API.

Comment: HTTP works, too, so long as you include it in your CSP and allow-intent declaration.

Comment: Ryan, I tried on html page :<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' content-src: http://localhost:myportnumber data: gap: ssl.gstatic.com http://localhost:myportnumber 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src "> and in config/xml : <allow-intent href="http://localhost:myportnumber/*" /> <allow-navigation href="http://localhost:myportnumber/*" /> but still has same issue. Can you tell me where am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's already added; but it does not show up here. See while adding http http://localhost:4545

Comment: I am having same issue is there any solution yet? does that mean we can not use ajax in cordova? that doesnt sound real .  @shyamsundarsinghtomar could you find anything by now?